# JTextArea row, columns and character relation

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

What's the relation between `JTextArea` row/column and the character that it could contains? For example,

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1,1);
```

how many character could this contain?

Comment: `how many character could contains?` - Try it and see what happens. Do you get 1 character or more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the relation between JTextArea row/columd and character that it could contains? for example,

```
JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1,1);
```

> how many character could contains?

The row and column fields have no bearing on how many characters the JTextArea can hold, just in how they may be displayed. It will mainly effect the preferredSize of the text component.

Comment: so, for find a right dimension for my JTextArea, i should try manually with different combinations?

Comment: @giozh: You should use whatever makes the most sense for your application. Note that even after setting these properties, the text component may not abide by your settings, especially if it is held in a layout manager that forces it to be a different size.